# Can I open mysql tunnel from with a iPython notebook cell (osx)

Tags: macos, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Tried using "Magics" and can successfully run:

```
%%bash
echo "hello from $BASH"
```

which returns:

```
hello from /bin/bash
```

But running this:

```
%%bash
ssh -C -N <foo user>@<bar server> -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306
```

does not permit running vanilla mysql query code against the tunnel connection.  Am I trying to do the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  So I have two options:

1. I can use the magic method of -

   %%bash
   ssh -C -N @ -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306
2. I can simply start the command with '!'

   !ssh -C -N @ -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306

BUT - be sure the end the tunnel command with a ';' so that output is suppressed and IPython Notebook isn't waiting for the tunnel command to return something before executing your SQL.  Example:

```
!ssh -C -N <foo user>@<bar server> -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306;
```